# Darken an inherited text color at runtime?

Tags: css, css-filters

Suppose I have an element where the text color is inherited:

```
element { color: inherited}
```

I'd also like to darken this on `hover`:

```
element:hover { color:darker(10%) }
```

Is there a pure css (No javascript) trick/hack for this that has fairly good browser support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use filter to get near to what you want to achieve.

see the attached demo

```css
.p{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial, sans-serif;
}

.c:hover{
  filter: brightness(0.2)
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c">hello</div>
```